# Prevent redirection when form is submitted programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a form on the html page which gets submitted by javascript in some cases. The problem is that browser window change its location to the action URL specified for this form. Is there any way to prevent it of working this way?

Comment: *How* does JavaScript submit the form?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to stay on the same page or do you want to submit the form in the 'background' using AJAX?

Comment: I want form to be submitted when user either refreshes (re-opens) or leaves the web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a javascript library to submit the form via Ajax (xhr) or submit to iframe

Full Jquery example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#yourForm').submit(captureSubmit)
    })

    function captureSubmit(event) {
        var frm = $(event.originalTarget);
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function(results) {
                // do stuff
                alert(results);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                // handle the error
                alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
            }
        });  
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form id="yourForm" action="foo.html" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[EDIT] made example more complete.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with asp.net ajax?

Comment: I'm testing in FireFox and get an error which says "frm.serialize() is not a function". What can I do about it?

Comment: You'll need to pull in the jquery library

Comment: you might get a code of 0 when testing it via file://. But a server (http://) should return a 200 code.

Answer (score 0):

Post it with Ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Submit with AJAX
2. Submit to an iframe